# Why does the second array remain empty?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The goal of this "counter" is to see how many different words are inside the "ToCount"string. To do that it makes ToCount an array and then iterates over the elements, checking if they already are there and if not, adding them there.

The ToCountArr2 remains empty after the loop and a length of 0 is being displayed. Why does that happen and what can I do about it?

I ran a debugger and saw that no elements are added to the second list, as if nothing appenned inside the "if" control if the i-th element of the first array already is inside the second array.

```
function counter(){
    var ToCount = document.getElementById("demo").value; //the contents of a textbox
    var ToCountArr1 = ToCount.split(" ");
    var ToCountArr2 = new Array;
    var i = 0;
    var lengthToCountArr1 = ToCountArr1.length;
    var wordToPush;
    while (i < lengthToCountArr1){
    if(ToCountArr2.includes(ToCountArr1[i] === false)) {
            wordToPush = ToCountArr1[i];
            ToCountArr2.push(wordToPush);
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    alert(ToCountArr2.length);
}
```

Comment: what you mean by this, `ToCountArr1[i] === false` ?

Comment: `if(ToCountArr2.includes(ToCountArr1[i]) === false)`

Comment: Voting to close as a typo

Comment: It was a typo, yes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this line `if(ToCountArr2.includes(ToCountArr1[i] === false))`. Here the braces need to be after `ToCountArr1[i]`, where as this line `ToCountArr1[i] === false)` is checking whether  that value in `ToCountArr1` is true or false.

This line

`if(ToCountArr2.includes(ToCountArr1[i] === false))` will be evaluated as

`if(ToCountArr2.includes(true/false))` 
depending on  result of `ToCountArr1[i] === false)`

```js
function counter() {
  var ToCount = document.getElementById("demo").value; //the contents of a textbox
  var ToCountArr1 = ToCount.split(" ");
  var ToCountArr2 = new Array;
  var i = 0;
  var lengthToCountArr1 = ToCountArr1.length;
  var wordToPush;

  while (i < lengthToCountArr1) {
    if (ToCountArr2.includes(ToCountArr1[i]) === false) {
      wordToPush = ToCountArr1[i];
      ToCountArr2.push(wordToPush);
    }
    i = i + 1;
  }
  console.log(ToCountArr2.length);
}

counter()
```

```html
<input type='text' id='demo' value='Test Values'>
```

You can minimize `if (ToCountArr2.includes(ToCountArr1[i]) === false) {` by replacing it with

`if (!ToCountArr2.includes(ToCountArr1[i])) {`

Answer (score 1):

Your `wordcount` function should use a parameter so you can *pass* a string in. This means you can use the `wordcount` function on an any string, not just the "demo" element. Also, this is a good time to learn about [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) -

```js
const wordcount = (str = "") =>
{ const result =
    new Map
  
  for (const s of str.split(/ /))
    if (s === "")
      continue
    else if (result.has(s))
      result.set(s, result.get(s) + 1)
    else
      result.set(s, 1)
  
  return Array.from(result.entries())
}

const prettyPrint = (value) =>
  console.log(JSON.stringify(value))
```

```html
<!-- pass this.value as the string for wordcount
  -- wordcount returns a value that we could use elsewhere
  -- prettyPrint displays the value to the console
  -->
<input onkeyup="prettyPrint(wordcount(this.value))">
```

Run the code snippet and copy/paste the following line into the field -

```
this is the captain speaking. is this the commander?
```

You will see this output -

```
[["this",2],["is",2],["the",2],["captain",1],["speaking.",1],["commander?",1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an working example. I think it will help you right way. Here I use indexOf to check the value exist on a array.

```
function counter(){
    var ToCount = "I am string just for text.";//document.getElementById("demo").value; //the contents of a textbox
    var ToCountArr1 = ToCount.split(" ");
    var ToCountArr2 = new Array;
    var i = 0;
    var lengthToCountArr1 = ToCountArr1.length;
    var wordToPush;
    while (i < lengthToCountArr1){
    if( ToCountArr2.indexOf(ToCountArr1[i]) == -1 ) {
            wordToPush = ToCountArr1[i];
            ToCountArr2.push(wordToPush);
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    alert(ToCountArr2.length);
}
counter();
```